# Find value of sibling key in php array

Tags: php, arrays, siblings

I have an array in PHP, here is a snippet:

```
$locations = array(
    array(
        "id" => 202,
        "name" => "GXP Club - Fable"
    ),

    array (
        "id" => 204,
        "name" => "GXP Club - Gray"
    )
);
```

What I know (from a GET) is the ID (202). What I would like to display is 
"Showing results for "
`( where $locations[?][id] = $_GET['id'] { echo $locations[?][name] } )` 
- if you will pardon my use of pseudo code.

Not sure what function is best or if I need to loop over the whole array to find that. Thanks.

Edit: for further clarification. I need to learn the [name] given the [id]

Comment: You need a loop, which you can `break` from on first match.  `foreach ($array as $subarr) {if ($subarr['id'] === $_GET['id']) {echo $subarr['name']; break;}}`

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm implementing. Too bad it's a comment and not an answer!

Comment: Yes. @Michael Please don't post answers as comments. Still annoying enough to make me comment 7 years later. I'd support you changing this now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach( $locations as $arr ) {
    if($arr['id'] == $_GET['id']) {
        echo $arr['name'];
        break;
    }
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

While looping over the array is the solution for the problem as described, it seems more optimal to change your array to be `$id=>$name` key-value pairs, instead of named key values if that's all the data in the array, e.g.:

```
$locations = array( '202' => 'GXP Club - Fable',
                    '204' => 'GXP Club - Gray',
             )
```

Alternatively, if there's more data, I'd switch to a nested data structure, e.g.:

```
$locations = array( '202' => array( 'name' => 'GXP Club - Fable', 'prop2' =>$prop2, etc),      
                    '204' => array( 'name' => 'GXP Club - Gray', 'prop2' =>$prop2, etc),
             )
```

That makes it so you can access data via ID (e.g. `$locations[$id]['name']`), which seems to be what you'd generally be wanting to do.

Comment: I appreciate your insight into how the array should be properly structured, but this is a JSON object so it's a little goofy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` function which applies your custom action to each element in given array.

```
array_map(
    function($arr) { if ($arr['id'] == $_GET['id']) echo $arr['name']; }, 
    $locations
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with PHP's built-in array functions<sup>*</sup> avoids a `foreach` loop:

```
<?php
$locations = [["id"=>202, "name"=>"GXP Club - Fable"], ["id"=>204, "name"=>"GXP Club - Gray"]];

$col = array_search(array_column($locations, "id"), $_GET["id"]);
echo $locations[$col]["name"];
```

Or, using a different method:

```
<?php
$locations = [["id"=>202, "name"=>"GXP Club - Fable"], ["id"=>204, "name"=>"GXP Club - Gray"]];

$result = array_filter($locations, function($v){ return $v["id"] == $_GET["id"]; });
echo array_shift($result)["name"];
```

---

<sup><sub>* Notably, `array_column()` was not available until PHP 5.5, released 10 months after this question was asked!</sub></sup>