# PHP JSON: Get value from siblings reference

Tags: php, json

I am working on a project that requires reading data from this terrible API that responds with terrible structured JSON data:

```
"finn-contanct": {...}
"finn-adata": {
    "@attributes": {
        "model": "https://cache.api.finn.no/iad/ad/model/car-used-sale"
    },
    "finn-field": [
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "name": "authorized_dealership",
                "value": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "name": "body_type",
                "value": "Stasjonsvogn"
            }
        },
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "name": "car_location",
                "value": "Norge"
            }
        },
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "name": "engine"
            },
            "finn-field": [
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "name": "effect",
                        "value": "90"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "name": "fuel",
                        "value": "Diesel"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {...},
    ]
}
```

How can i dynamically get the values under each attribute based on the siblings name value? Ideally with a function that accepts one parameter that finds the value in there by providing a key corresponding to the value i'm looking for.

Here is an example of what i'm expecting:
Given a function that expects one parameter: `getAttrValue('key')` I want to get the value under the @attributes sibling. So if I use the function like this: `getAttrValue('body_type')` i'm simply expecting this back: `Stasjonsvogn`. I don't really care about nested items. So if I do this: `getAttrValue('fuel')` I'm simply expecting: `Diesel`

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182575/find-value-of-sibling-key-in-php-array) here on SO. But the problem with that method is that it doesn't work well with nested items. So does anyone have a method that would work with the data-structure I got above here?

The response is a total mess and I don't know how to handle it, nor how to Google it properly. So any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Why not recursively flatten this to a normal structure, and then you can access things directly?

Comment: @Brad That data is returned from an external API. I cannot modify it. I wish I could though.

Comment: Of course you can modify it... inside your client-side application.  Take the JSON response, pre-process it before dealing with it in the rest of your code.  You could even make a simple JavaScript class that uses getters/setters to read/write from this structure if you wanted.

Comment: Can you give some examples of expected output from this data?

Comment: @Brad So how would I go about that? I can't even figure out how to read the values I need. The API changes structure for every response. So i cannot assume the data is in the same index as the last request.

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen Take a look at `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`.  That will help you iterate through the structure.

Comment: @Nick I'm not really expecting an output. What I'm looking for is a function that can find the values under each attribute based on the key I need. The output i'm looking for is the value of the sibling corresponding to the key I provide.

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen so what I'm asking for is, given your sample data, what might be some input values and corresponding output values for that function?

Comment: @Nick Something like this: `getAttrValue('body_type')` should return `Stasjonsvogn` in this case. And for the nested value: `getAttrValue('fuel')` should simply return `Diesel`

Comment: What if there are multiple nested attributes with the same name? Is that possible?

Comment: @Nick No, that is not possible.

Comment: Generally speaking, the API should accept a Query/Search with specific criteria or terms you're looking for. i.e. the list of available body types for cars of a specific manufacturer, etc. So "*Ideally with a function that accepts one parameter that finds the value in there by providing a key corresponding to the value i'm looking for.*" would be the API search.

Comment: @fyrye I'm not looking for a query filter. I simply need to extract information out of this terrible JSON-structure reliabley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect attributes into associative array recursively:

```php
function collectAttributes($data)
{
    $attributes = [];
    $nodeAttribute = isset($data['@attributes']) ? $data['@attributes'] : [];

    //collect current node attribute value
    if (isset($nodeAttribute['name'])) {
        $attributes[$nodeAttribute['name']] = isset($nodeAttribute['value']) ? $nodeAttribute['value'] : '';
    }

    //collect nested attributes recursively
    foreach ($data as $nestedNode) {
        if (is_array($nestedNode)) {
            $attributes = array_merge($attributes, collectAttributes($nestedNode));
        }
    }

    return $attributes;
}
```

And then use result as simple associative array:

```php
$data = json_decode($inputJson, true);
$atttributes = collectAttributes($data);
echo $attributes['fuel']; //don't forget isset checking if you are not sure about content
```

But if you have attributes with same name you'll see only latest this way.

Comment: You are the hero of the day. Works perfectly!